# SCP File Transfer Between Pi and Windows

Tags: ssh, window, raspberry-pi, scp

With pscp in windows command line, i can send file from Windows to Pi or i can copy a file from Pi to Windows. But opposite does not work. I cant send a file from pi to windows with pi's terminal.

```
scp text.txt username@192.168.1.100:C:/Users/Desktop/
```

or C/Users/Desktep with out colon.
Both does not work. It returns nothing. After few minutes it says connection timed out.

Comment: Do you have running `sshd` server on your windows machine. I guess not so there is no reason why it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scp is a client that connects to a server. Your Pi is running an SSH server which allows you to connect to it from other machines using pscp or scp (depending on what OS). So to make it work the other way, you need to install an SSH server on your windows machine.

I followed this article to install on my windows machine: 
http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/07/30/how-to-install-openssh-on-windows-10/

Sometime in the future based on the announcement by Microsoft at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2015/06/03/looking-forward-microsoft-support-for-secure-shell-ssh.aspx it appears Windows will have SSH server.

Comment: thak you i solved problem with calling files from winodws